# OutOfMemory error in Android XML Pull parser

Tags: android, xml-parsing

I parse an XML document from a HTTPResponse.
Previously I initiated the parser with a String object created from the InputStream.

When I changed the setup so the inputStream isused directly in the parser I get OutOfMemory Exceptions.

The strange thing is that parsing the String worked without problems before, so I wonder why the InputStream should need more memory.

Previous code:

```
final byte[] encodedResponseBytes = IOUtils.toByteArray(httpResponse
            .getEntity().getContent());

String message = new String(encodedResponseBytes);

parser.setInput(new StringReader(message));
```

New code:

```
InputStream stream = httpResponse
            .getEntity().getContent();
parser.setInput(stream, null);
```

Comment: How big is your XML document? Perhaps SAX parsing might be a better choice if it is very large, that way they whole thing doesn't need to be in memory at once.

Comment: not relevant to the question, but instead of IOUtils and new String, consider EntityUtils.toString(httpResponse.getEntity());

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By changing the code I don't have a problem anymore:

`InputStream stream = request.getResponseStream();
reader = new InputStreamReader(stream);
this.xmlParser.setInput(reader);`